# How to install OTP erlang-crypto library

Tags: erlang, couchdb

I wanted build erlang from source.After build I tried to check crypto library as follow:

```
$erl -env ERL_LIBS $ERL_LIBS:/path/to/couchdb/lib -couch_ini -s crypto
1> crypto:md5_init().
<<>>
```

I have expected

```
1> crypto:md5_init().
<<1,35,69,103,137,171,205,239,254,220,186,152,118,84,50,
  16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...>>
```

I have installed openssl, openssl-dev, before building erlang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the `crypto:md5_init()` return value. It's an example of a "magic binary" that represents an internal data structure of the Erlang runtime. If you use it as documented, it works perfectly:

```
1> C = crypto:md5_init().
<<>>
2> C2 = crypto:md5_update(C, "some data").
<<>>
3> crypto:md5_final(C2).
<<30,80,33,10,2,2,73,127,183,155,195,139,106,222,108,52>>
```

That example is from Erlang 19. If we go back to 18.3 or older, we get this:

```
1> C = crypto:md5_init().
<<1,35,69,103,137,171,205,239,254,220,186,152,118,84,50,
  16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...>>
2> C2 = crypto:md5_update(C, "some data").
<<1,35,69,103,137,171,205,239,254,220,186,152,118,84,50,
  16,72,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,115,111,109,101,32,...>>
3> crypto:md5_final(C2).
<<30,80,33,10,2,2,73,127,183,155,195,139,106,222,108,52>>
```

Note that the final MD5 results of the two examples are identical.